Rar архивация по списку
Не подскажите как можно заставить консольный WinRAR делать архив по файлу списка? Есть заранее заготовленный файл списка, надо что-бы в бакап попадали файлы из разных частей системы, и не трогались остальные файлы.
C:\Folder1\
C:\Folder2\Subfolder1\
C:\Folder2\File1.txt


http://acritum.com/winrar/console-rar-manual

@Эникейщик Cпасибо большое!

на какой старьё вы дали ссылку!  в папке winrar (после установки) есть файл rar.txt, там то же самое но для установленной версии

@ESkri ну дай ссылку на файл в папке winrar, в чем проблема-тт

это типа ты сострил что ли? )))
